# One-to-many relation between type and aspect?

Tags: alfresco

I have the next [content model](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/24633336/contentModel.png).:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<model name="sm:modelContent" xmlns="http://www.alfresco.org/model/dictionary/1.0">

<description>Content Model</description>
<author>Arak</author>
<version>1.0</version>

<imports>
    <import uri="http://www.alfresco.org/model/dictionary/1.0"
        prefix="d" />
    <import uri="http://www.alfresco.org/model/bpm/1.0"
        prefix="bpm" />
</imports>

<namespaces>
    <namespace uri="http://www.some.com/model/content/1.0" prefix="sm" />
</namespaces>

<!-- Types -->

<types>
    <type name="sm:contentParent">
        <parent>cm:content</parent>
    </type>

    <type name="sm:contentChildren1">
        <parent>sm:contentParent</parent>
    </type>

    <type name="sm:contentChildren2">
        <parent>sm:contentParent</parent>
    </type>

    <type name="sm:contentChildren3">
        <parent>sm:contentParent</parent>
    </type>
</types>

<!-- Aspects -->

<aspects>

  <!-- An Aspect -->

    <aspect name="sm:otherOtherAspect">

        <properties>

      ....

    </properties>
    </aspect>

  <!-- Other Aspect -->

  <aspect name="sm:otherAspect">

    <properties>

      ....

    </properties>
  </aspect>


  <!-- An Other Aspect -->

    <aspect name="sm:anOtherAspect1">
      <properties>

       ....

      </properties>
    </aspect>

    <aspect name="sm:anOtherAspect2">
      <properties>

       ....

      </properties>
    </aspect>

    <aspect name="sm:anOtherAspect3">
      <properties>

       ....

      </properties>
    </aspect>

    ... can exist N ...

    <!-- Other Other Aspect -->

    <aspect name="sm:anAspect1">
      <properties>

        ....

      </properties>
    </aspect>

    <aspect name="sm:anAspect2">
      <properties>

        ....

      </properties>
    </aspect>

    <aspect name="sm:anAspect3">
      <properties>

        ....

      </properties>
    </aspect>

    ... can exist N ...

</aspects>
```

Depending of the type of content:

- sm:contentChildren1 can have a 1 "anOtherAspect" and 0 "anAspect".
- sm:contentChildren2 can have a N "anOtherAspect" and 0 "anAspect".
- sm:contentChildren3 can have a N "anOtherAspect" and N "anAspect".

These relationships exist between types and aspects? (one-to-one or one-to-many) How can use it?, if not exist, I can simulate this relationship in any way?

I would like to work aspects based on a relationship and not creating them one by one (exaggerating the value of N, and creating a lot of aspects).

Greetings,
Pablo.

Answer (score 1):

Alfresco aspects are on-to-one in that an Alfresco node can only have one instance of a particular aspect and a particular instance of an aspect is only associated with one node.

You have two options for getting multiple values on your node.

1. Designate your properties as `<multiple>true</multiple>` which means that it can hold multiple values. More details on this here:
   http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/concepts/metadata-model-props.html
2. Use peer associations. These allow you to have any kind of multiplicity relationship between nodes. Also bear in mind that the content of Alfresco nodes can be empty and you can use one only to hold metadata in a sense using it as an aspect. These are detailed in the data dictionary guide:
   http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Data_Dictionary_Guide#Peer_.28Non-Child.29_Associations